# Как на языке СИ разбить данные файла по структурам?

Tags: c, файлы, структуры

У нас имеется файл, в котором записаны 6 элементов данных через пробел.
Например:

```
|Петров Акакий Анатольевич 12 01 2077 |
|Мартынов Антон Григорьевич 18 12 2078|
|Руднев Александр Федорович 11 08 2065|
```

И имеется структура типа:

```
struct baza
{
    char first_name[size];
    char last_name[size];
    char patron[size];
    char data1[size];
    char data2[size];
    char data3[size];
};
```

как на языке СИ написать функцию,которая читает с файла текст и записывает по членам структуры.
Вот так:

```
struct baza str[size];
str[0].first_name="Петров";
str[0].last_name="Акакий";
str[0].patron="Анатольевич";
str[0].data1="12";
str[0].data2="01";
str[0].data3="2077";
str[1].first_name="Мартынов";
str[1].last_name="Антон";
```

И так далее.
Что-бы потом с помощью обычного printf можно было вывести эту структуру поэлементно.

Что-бы можно было потом с нею химичить.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как это сделать:

1) открыть файл

2) Посмотреть размер в строках

3) выделить память под нужное кол-во объектов

4) считать данные через fscanf

Вот банальный пример без обработки ошибок считывания и формата

Вам надо только поменять fscanf (переписать под свою структуру)

Пример файла data

```
1 1.1
2 2.2
3 3.3
```

Пример кода :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct s
{
    int a;
    double b;
};


int main()
{
   FILE* in;
   in = fopen("data", "r");
   if(!in)
   {
       printf("Error : Unable ot open file\n");
   }
   // размер файла в строках
   unsigned int lines = 0;
   int ch;
   while(!feof(in))
   {
      ch = fgetc(in);
      if(ch == '\n')
      {
          lines++;
      }
   }
   // возврат к началу файла
   fseek(in, 0, SEEK_SET);

   printf("Lines : %d\n", lines);

   // считывание
   struct s* data = malloc(lines * sizeof(struct s));

   for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
       fscanf(in,"%d %lf", &data[i].a, &data[i].b);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
       printf("%d, %lf\n", data[i].a, data[i].b);
   }

   free(data);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

как то так.

```
function fillStruct() {
        var strings = file.readLines('path/to/file');
        var struct = new Struct(strings.length);

        for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
          var data = strings[i].split(' ');
          struct[i].first_name = data[0];
          struct[i].last_name = data[1];
          struct[i].patron = data[2];
          struct[i].data1 = data[3];
          struct[i].data2 = data[4];
          struct[i].data3 = data[5];
        }
      }
```

Comment: Что-то странный у вас С, надо признаться.

Comment: Что за язык??? fвопрос с меткой С

Comment: это просто алгоритм. это не конкретный язык

Comment: переписать на си делов 5 минут.

Comment: Я только начал учить,дальше си не продвигался, немного не понимаю пару моментов. Функция, в ней открывается файл? и 2 строку в функции не очень понимаю, и в цикле 2 строку не понимаю.Можно поподробнее?

Comment: читаеш файл по строчно. создаеш массив структур размеро с кол-во строк.пребираеш строки  йиклом. на каждой итерайии делиш строку еще на несколько строк, разделителем выступает пробел. получается еще 1 массив ну и потом записываеш даныне это масcива в структуру с индексом i

Comment: Ладно,спасибо,разберусь